# C# subscript string including variable

Tags: c#, string

I know that in C# to write subscript, I should use Unicode
for example 
I want to write H<sub>2</sub>O , I should write

```
String str = "H"+"\x2082"+ "O"
```

But I want to put variable type of int instead of 2 in formula
How can I create a string with variable, which is written in subscript?

Comment: Is this only going to be for numbers?

Comment: Yes it will be only for numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unicode, the subscript digits are assigned consecutive codepoints, ranging from `U+2080` to `U+2089`. Thus, if you take the Unicode character for subscript 0 – namely, `'₀'` – then you can obtain the subscript character for any other digit by adding its numeric value to the former's codepoint.

If your integer will only consist of a single digit:

```
int num = 3;
char subscript = (char)('₀' + num);   // '₃'
```

If your integer may consist of any number of digits, then you can apply the same addition to each of its digits individually. The easiest way of enumerating an integer's digits is by converting it to a string, and using the LINQ `Select` operator to get the individual characters. Then, you subtract `'0'` from each character to get the digit's numeric value, and add it to `'₀'` as described above. The code below assumes that `num` is non-negative.

```
int num = 351;
var chars = num.ToString().Select(c => (char)('₀' + c - '0'));
string subscript = new string(chars.ToArray());   // "₃₅₁"
```

Comment: single digit is working fine but the second (with many digits) is not working

Comment: I don't understand the second line

Comment: `U+208x` is the codepoint for subscript of `x`. If you take `U+2080` (which is `'₀'`) and add `x` to it, then you will get the codepoint you want.

Comment: "Subtract '0' from each character to get the digit's numeric value." `'x' - '0'` gives `x`.

Answer (score 1):

[This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) shows you all the unicode codes for super and subscript symbols.

You can simply create a method which maps these:

```
public string GetSubScriptNumber(int i)
{
    // get the code as needed
}
```

I will give a few hints to help you along:

- Unfortunately you can't just do `return "\x208" + i` so you'll need to do a switch for the numbers `0-9` or add the integer to `"\x2080"`.
- If you only need `0-9` then do some error checking that the input is in that range and throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
- If you need all `int`s then you may find it easier splitting it up into each digit and getting a `char` for each of those - watch out for negative numbers but there is a character for subscript minus sign too!

To include the number in your string, you can use something like `String.Format`:

```
String.Format("H{0}O", GetSubScriptNumber(i))
```

Comment: it will receive the int number, but then the problem won't be solved

Comment: as I said I want to make a string that includes variable(and the variable must be written in subscript)

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape it

```
String str = "H" + "\\x2082" + "O";
```

or use verbose strings

```
String str = "H" + @"\x2082" + "O";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we don't understand your question.  Several of the answers above seem correct.  Does this work?

```
static string GetSubscript(int value)
{
  StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (char digit in value.ToString())
    returnValue.Append((char)(digit - '0' + '₀'));
  return returnValue.ToString();
}

string waterFormula = "H" + GetSubscript(2) + "0"  // H₂O
string methaneFormula = "CH" + GetSubscript(4) // CH₄
```